# Show where column equals a specific data?

Tags: coldfusion

I have a column(cse_dept) where it has integers , I would only like to show the columns where it equals 12 or 39.
Is there a way to do this?

```
  <cfif  (#GetCurrentUser.cse_dept# eq '12'39') >
    <h1>test</h1>
 </cfif>
```

It does not show me a error it just doesn't work the way I would like it.

Comment: You should probably be doing this in the SQL instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `listFind`. If the value of `GetCurrentUser.cse_dept` is 12 or 39 `listFind` will return the a number greater than 0

```
<cfif listFind('12,39', GetCurrentUser.cse_dept)>
  <h1>test</h1>
</cfif>
```

`listFind` is case sensitive in case you were searching for something other than numbers. If you need a case-insensitve search you can use `listFindNoCase`

Alternatively you could check for each value separately

```
<cfif GetCurrentUser.cse_dept EQ 12 OR GetCurrentUser.cse_dept EQ 39>
  <h1>test</h1>
</cfif>
```

If you want to check if `GetCurrentUser.cse_dept` is 12 or 39 for any result in your query you can do

```
<cfif listFind(valueList(getCurrentUser), 12) OR listFind(valueList(getCurrentUser), 39)>
  <h1>test</h1>
</cfif>
```

Comment: If GetCurrentUser is a query that returns more than one row, this answer is incorrect.  You would need to apply the ValueList function as well.  However, there is not enough information to determine whether or not it is a query at all.

Comment: @DanBracuk I would assume "getCurrentUser" means one record is returned, but if not you can't use a valueList with one listFind you would need two separate listFinds

Comment: Yes it is a query, returns more than one row.

Comment: So you want to know if cse_dept is 12 or 39 in any row of the entire query?

Comment: @mattburshe YES in the entire query.

Comment: @user3408399 I updated my answer to have an option to look at all results in the query and return true if 12 ro 39 are found

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this:

Method 1 - Query of Queries

```
<cfquery name="q1" dbtype="query">
   select count(*) records
   from GetCurrentUser 
   where cse_dept in (12,39)
</cfquery>

<cfif q1.records gt 0>
do something
</cfif>
```

Method 2 - List Functions

```
<cfif ListFind(ValueList(GetCurrentUser.cse_dept), 12)
+
ListFind(ValueList(GetCurrentUser.cse_dept), 39) gt 0>
do something
</cfif>
```

Method 3 - Array Functions

```
<cfif ArrayFind(GetCurrentUser['cse_dept'], 12) 
+
ArrayFind(GetCurrentUser['cse_dept'], 39) gt 0>
do something
</cfif>
```

Method 2 is very similar to Matt's second suggstion.  One difference is the use of a ValueList function.  The second is that instead of using "or", I added the function results together.  The results are the same.

Method 3 is probably the fastest.  However, depending on where those numbers 12 and 39 come from, Method 1 might be a better approach.